# Power statistics - change grid intervals on time axis?

Tags: gnome-power-manager

I am looking at battery charge history in the power statistics monitor in Ubuntu Mate. I think this is the same as in Gnome or other related desktop environments.
https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-power-manager/unstable/statistics.html.en

One thing I always found silly in this display is the steps on the time axis.

The time axis has 2h, 6h or 1day, but the axis is split into 10 intervals, hence each interval may be e.g. 36 minutes.

This means the interval lines are completely confusing when trying to determine percentage lost per hour.

Is it possible to change the time axis intervals? E.g. in a config file somewhere?

(If not, I should probably create a feature request somewhere)

Comment: Creating a feature request sounds like a good idea.

Comment: where would I do this?